# How to obtain the average backend response time from nginx live?

Tags: http, nginx, response-time

I am trying to monitor the nginx backend speed of response. While I enabled response time and added it to the HTTP logs, this is not of much help for monitoring the instance live.

I want to be able to read this every minute, computing the AVG response time so I can add this data to our monitoring services.

How can I obtain this?

I know that one would say to tail the logs, but that's not very easy (maybe someone has some example scripts from a similar kind of tasks). Logs can also be rotated.

Obviously the solution should be ok to be used without having to add a huge load on the server itself, it would not be the first case where monitoring would help bringing the stuff down.

Any scripting would do, but I have a personal preference for python and bash ones :)

Comment: This question appears to belong on another site in the Stack Exchange network because its not about programming. Perhaps [Super User](https://www.superuser.com/) or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/).

Comment: Requires coding! That's not something to configure...